# Load JSON data using the dropdown menu and refresh the div area with the new results in a web site

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to load JSON data from a drop down menu to a div area which would be refreshed with the new results, i have manged to get the data and show it in the div area without using the drop down menu, but cannot find a way to call the required data using the drop down menu.

the below code is to bring up part of the json data from the json file that is present which is working when i load the web page, but what i need is that when the user clicks on the drop-down menu and clicks any of the links, the relevant json data will be displayed

```
$(function loadpc()
{
    $(document).ready(function () { // load json file using jquery ajax
        $.getJSON('PCproducts.json', function (data) {
            var output = '<div id="row">';
            var count = 1;
            $.each(data.pc, function (key, val) {
                output += '<div id="holding-area">';
                output += '<div id="img-area">' +
                   '<img id="img" src="'+val.imgpath+'" alt="'+ val.title +'" /></div>';
                output += '<div id="info">';
                output += '<h2>' + val.title + '</h2>';
                output += '<p>' + val.category + '</p>';
                output += '<p>' + val.develop + '</p>';
                output += '<p>' + val.released + '</p>';
                output += '<p>' + val.price + '</p>';
                output += '<p>' + val.quantity + '</p>';
                output += '<p><input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn" /></p>'
                output += '</div>';
                output += '</div>';
                if(count%2 == 0){
                  output += '</div><div id="row">'
                  }
                  count++;
            });
            output += '</div>';
            $('#content-2-1').html(output);     // replace all existing content
        });
    });
});
```

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction as i have been trying for a long time with no success

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery template is the simple manner :)

You may find some info there [jquery template documentation](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template#jqueryloadtemplate)

jquery template is a simple type formatted like this  i took it from one of my project:

```
 <script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="tplmsg">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-1">
        <img src="${src}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="${title}" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-11">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
            <p class="title"><a href="/<%=Session("lang")%>/${cat}/${sct}/${rws(title)}/${prov}/${id}">${getSubstring(title,0,100)}</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 btf" >
            <p class="adsdts"><strong>Data: </strong>${parseJsonDate(DateAdd)} &nbsp;           
               <strong>Prezzo:</strong>${price} &nbsp;
                <strong>Provincia:</strong><a href="/<%=Session("lang")%>/<%=Resources.COREMSG.ANNUNCIPROV%>/${rws(pvname)}">${pvname}</a> 
               <%--<strong>Provincia:</strong><a href="/<%=Session("lang")%>/${cat}/${sct}/${pvname}">${pvname}</a>--%>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr />
</script>
```

In abovesnippet you may see some stuff which is vbnet related how ever logic is the same.
Then you may fill it with simple js function like this:

```
function getAds(task,token) {

var qry='task='+task+'&token=' +token;
$.ajax(
{
type: "POST", url: url, data: qry
,
 success: function (msg) {

    if (msg.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
        $("#").html(msg.error);
        return;
    }
    else if (msg.hasOwnProperty('empty')) {
        $("#result").html(msg.empty);
        return;
    }
    else {
        //reular version
        $("#"+msg.tmpl).tmpl(msg.data, null).appendTo("#"+msg.result);
    }
},
error: function (msg) {
    $("#result").html("errore durante l'elaborazione");
}
 });


}
```

That's all simple and fast.

Comment: Hi i tried out the above but still to no success, to show the required data from the navigation menu area.