# repeater with custom filters in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ajax, repeater

I have repeater control in which i am binding data from sql server database, Now i have number of records showing on my page but i want that i can filter my records according to dropdown selected. I need 4-5 dropdowns control thats depend on my need and i don't want my page to refresh while filtering.
Below is the example, this website using checkboxes too but i need only dropdowns...
http://www.phonearena.com/phones/full#/phones/full/

Give me any idea how to start, i think ajax is the thing i need. Suggest some examples if you have.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the right solution.

Personally i suggest you jquerytemplate and ajax call few row code to achive your goal you may find more info here [Load JSON data using the dropdown menu and refresh the div area with the new results in a web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22878600/load-json-data-using-the-dropdown-menu-and-refresh-the-div-area-with-the-new-res/22878731#22878731)

It is a good point to start and you can make more stuff with this logic :) really simple and fluid code :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a client-side framework (so in JavaScript) like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), [BackboneJS](http://backbonejs.org/) or [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/). They all provide ways to work with collections in JavaScript (like filtering in this case). You won't need Ajax excepted for the first load or if you want to do some paging. And because it's all client-side it will be far more fluid than re-downloading at every criteria change.